# Windows - Where to locate .bashrc file to increase heap size

Tags: java, windows, grails, heap-memory, heap-size

Actually I'm working on grails application which running smothly but after some time its throwing `exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` for this i received some solutions like

1. Adding Env. Variable `GRAILS_OPTS = -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m` even tried `GRAILS_OPTS = -Xms512m -Xmx1024m`
2. Adding variable  `JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=96m` to startGrails.bat file
3. is adding `export GRAILS_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -server"` in .bashrc file can anyone tell me where is this file located.

No luck with option 1 and 2.

Using **Windows 10**

Comment: you don't need `.bashrc`, it's a Unix shell config. I'm sure you aren't using Unix shell under Windows 10

Comment: @IgorArtamonov No. I'm not using unix shell.  Do you know how to increase heap size for grails application

Comment: which version of grails?

Comment: grails version 1.3.7

Comment: option 2 should work then (how did you add it to bat file?)

Comment: also, i think you should ask a different question. it's not about .bashrc really

Comment: yeah. and accept the answer since you get information about bashrc in 3 minutes :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

It is a hidden file (note dot as a first char) so please open it in the terminal with this command (if you are using gedit ofc):
`sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`

**update:** however after reading your question once again i think that you are working on Windows and your option 3 is a linux alternative to #1. isn't it?